# How can birds keep their eyes moist during flight?

Tags: zoology

Mammals have an upper lid and small mass  of tissue in the upper corner known as nictitating membrane. This helps keep the eyes clean; birds can moisten their eyes in flight using this membrane without blinking. How does this work?

Answer (score 0):

Because the nictitating membrane secretes a fluid that is resistant to evaporation. Therefore, birds need not blink their eyes during flight.

Comment: Please do add some solid references.